# How to generate 2 cases not 1 only in c#

Tags: c#, random

I am trying to generate 2 cases.  I want to make it choose 2 cases.

my code

```
#region IronTiger Boss
            if (Owner.Name == "IronTiger")
            {
                byte times = (byte)Kernel.Random.Next(1, 3);
                byte ref_times = (byte)Kernel.Random.Next(1, 6);
                for (byte i = 0; i < times; i++)
                {
                    uint Uid = 0;
                    byte type = (byte)Kernel.Random.Next(1, 28);

                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Uid = 824020;    
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            Uid = 824019;    
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            Uid = 824018;    
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            Uid = 823060;    
                            break;   

                        case 5:
                            Uid = 823061;    
                            break;

                        case 6:
                            Uid = 823060;    
                            break;

                        case 7:
                            Uid = 823059;    
                            break;

                        case 8:
                            Uid = 823058;    
                            break;

                        case 9:
                            Uid = 822072;    
                            break;

                        case 10:
                            Uid = 822071;    
                            break;

                        case 11:
                            Uid = 821033;    
                            break;

                        case 12:
                            Uid = 820076;    
                            break;

                        case 13:
                            Uid = 820075;    
                            break;

                        case 14:
                            Uid = 820074;    
                            break;

                        case 15:
                            Uid = 820073;    
                            break;

                        case 16:
                            Uid = 800917;    
                            break;

                        case 17:
                            Uid = 800811;    
                            break;

                        case 18:
                            Uid = 800810;    
                            break;

                        case 19:
                            Uid = 800725;    
                            break;

                        case 20:
                            Uid = 800618;    
                            break;

                        case 21:
                            Uid = 800522;    
                            break;

                        case 22:
                            Uid = 800422;    
                            break;

                        case 23:
                            Uid = 800255;    
                            break;

                        case 24:
                            Uid = 800255;    
                            break;

                        case 25:
                            Uid = 800142;    
                            break;

                        case 26:
                            Uid = 800111;    
                            break;

                        case 27:
                            Uid = 800020;    
                            break;

                        case 28:
                            Uid = 821034;    
                            break;    
                    }

                    if (Uid != 0)
                    {
                        killer.Owner.Inventory.Add(Uid, 0, 1);
                        DeadPool.Kernel.SendWorldMessage(new DeadPool.Network.GamePackets.Message("Congratulations! " + killer.Name + " has killed " + Name + " and dropped! " + Database.ConquerItemInformation.BaseInformations[Uid].Name + "!", System.Drawing.Color.White, 2011), Program.Values);
                        return;
                    }    
                }
            }
            #endregion
```

When its done, it gives me 1 case only. I want to make it generate 2 cases not 1.  How can i fix this and also, how do I add more cases?

Comment: What do you mean by case when you say '1 case'?

Comment: i mean it choose from case 1: to case 28: , 1 case only not 2 cases like what i want you got it? @TimmyJim

Comment: Only one case will be executed depending on the value of `type`, because `type` can only hold one value... How exactly do you want 2 cases to be executed? Your question is very hard to understand, please elaborate it (and not in the comments, edit your post)

Comment: Why not combine the logic of two cases together in one if you want both to be executed? BTW Why do you want two case statements to be executed? You might get a workaround.

Comment: Do not use a case here. Put all uid values into an array and get the desired value via array index: Uid = idvalues[type]

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Uid != 0)
{
  killer.Owner.Inventory.Add(Uid, 0, 1);
  DeadPool.Kernel.SendWorldMessage(new DeadPool.Network.GamePackets.Message("Congratulations! " + killer.Name + " has killed " + Name + " and dropped! " + Database.ConquerItemInformation.BaseInformations[Uid].Name + "!", System.Drawing.Color.White, 2011), Program.Values);
  return;
}
```

See that `return` there? You do know what it does? It returns when a value is found so there is no second loop performed ever.

You should learn how to use a debugger to go through the code and these issues become immediately clear.